# PHP: \r character being ignored

Tags: php, string, linefeed

I have a string `$s="one\rtwo\rthree\rfour\rfive"` and when I do `print $s` I expect to see `five` only because the linefeed resets the line.

Instead I seem to be seeing `one  two  three  four   five`.

What's going on?

Comment: Are you trying to display this in a web browser?

Comment: Yes - I essentially run a shell script via PHP, and the shell script outputs progress percentages ('1%\r2%\r3% etc'). The `print` function is prompted whenever `fgets` detects a newline, but it also seems to be interpreting `\r` as a newline too. Anyway to override this?

Comment: `print(end(explode("\r", $s)));` will do what you are asking for.
EDIT: I just saw your previous comment about this being in the shell. This isn't what you want. It will print multiple lines.

Comment: Excellent! I seem to be missing the first part of the string, but I am getting `100%` flushed only for each file processed!

Comment: So my comment worked for you?

Comment: Yep - I adapted it to: `$data = explode("\r", $s); print "$data[0]" . end($data);`, but yes it works perfectly - thank you!

Comment: Awesome! I will create an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to rewrite a line in a console window (like it appears you are trying to do) you can do something like this:

`#!/c/PHP/php-7.0/php.exe
    <?php
    for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++){
        fwrite(STDOUT, "\r$i%");
    }`

or if you want only the last portion of a string separated by Carriage returns you can do something like this:

`$endVal = end(explode("\r", $s));
    print($endVal);`